# Vue js send parametr in route

Tags: vue.js

**i use parameter in route url and this is work.**

```
    {
    path: '/productdetail/:productId',
    name: 'ProductDetail',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ '../views/product/ProductDetail')
}
<router-link :to="{name: 'ProductDetail', params: {productId: 1}}"></router-link>
```

**and when refresh page i get this error in console:**

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: you probably have syntax error somewhere else since the router-link syntax looks right above

Comment: Your HTTP server is producing some error - most probably responding with HTML content when a JS was requested. Check the Network log.